# Passing json object to collection causes errors

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

So this is my code so far. Just trying to understand how all these libraries work but cant find the problem. Im using RequireJS, BackboneJS, Handlebars.

As you can see in ClientsView.js im trying to create a new instance of ClientsCollection and pass json object. 
This is the error I get in the chrome console, if you expand it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefinedbackbone.js:689 i.extend.setbackbone.js:638 i.extend.addbackbone.js:769 i.extend.resetbackbone.js:607 e.Collectionbackbone.js:1566 sClientsView.js:17 Backbone.View.extend.initializebackbone.js:1001 e.Viewbackbone.js:1566 srouter.js:10 initializeapp.js:9 initializemain.js:15 (anonymous function)require.js:27 d.execCbrequire.js:10 orequire.js:12 arequire.js:12 orequire.js:12 arequire.js:12 orequire.js:12 arequire.js:12 orequire.js:12 arequire.js:12 orequire.js:12 arequire.js:12 orequire.js:15 xrequire.js:15 mrequire.js:21 g.completeLoadrequire.js:27 d.onScriptLoad
```

However if I pass nothing there are no errors.

I checked requireJS paths and names, nothing.

There must be something very stupid that I am missing. Thank you for your time.

ClientModel.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'handlebars',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Handlebars, Backbone){

    var ClientModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'ID' : '',
            'name' : '',
            'birthdate' : '',
            'email' : ''
        }
    });
});
```

ClientsCollection.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'handlebars',
    'backbone',
    'models/Client/ClientModel'
], function(_, handlebars, backbone, ClientModel){

    var ClientsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: ClientModel,

        //initialize: function(models, options) {},

        // comparator: function(client) {
        //  return client.get('name');
        // }
    });

    return ClientsCollection;
});
```

ClientsView.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'handlebars',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/clients/ClientsListTemplate.html',
    'collections/ClientsCollection/ClientsCollection'
], function($, _, Handlebars, Backbone, ClientsListTemplate, ClientsCollection){

    var ClientsView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'div',

        template: Handlebars.compile(ClientsListTemplate),

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new ClientsCollection([ { 'ID' : 1, 'name' : 'egis', 'birthdate' : '02', 'email' : 'email' } ]);
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template({ clients : this.collection.toJSON() }));
            return this;
        }
    });

    return ClientsView;
});
```

router.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'handlebars',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/clients/ClientsView'
], function($, _, Handlebars, backbone, ClientsView){

    var initialize = function() {
        var newClientsView = new ClientsView();
        $('#clients-list').html(newClientsView.render().el);
    }

    return {
            initialize: initialize
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks, actually I tried one last time to find the bug and found it. It was that there were no return statement at the end of ClientModel.js

Comment: @DasBoot Ah, missed that one! That would account for your Model appearing to be undefined.

Comment: Actually I tested those other bugs that you noticed, none of them were treated as bugs and worked either way. Whether its backbone or Backbone. And also this idAttribute, didnt make any change unless it gives additional functionality manipulating with data.

Answer (score 1):

I think your model is missing the `idAttribute`.

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'handlebars',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Handlebars, Backbone){

    var ClientModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        idAttribute: 'ID',

        defaults: {
            'ID' : '',
            'name' : '',
            'birthdate' : '',
            'email' : ''
        }
    });
});
```

By default, Backbone will look for a property name of lowercase `id` to uniquely identify each of your models unless you specifically tell it otherwise.

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed. Actually I have tried this way before only with backbones, everything was ok but now as im using requireJS im not even sure maybe there is something with paths and all these modules but I have already checked these.

Comment: Your lack of an `idAttribute` is still a problem but trying to decipher your error log, it looks like your model is undefined. Is it possible that `'models/Client/ClientModel'` is the incorrect path to your model?